# Why avoid dot operator chaining

Tags: coding-style, refactoring

There are two code snippets:

```
someObject.getBla1().getBla2().performBlah();
```

And the second one:

```
bla1=someObject.getBla1();
bla2=bla1.getBla2();
bla2.performBlah();
```

I am always told to avoid the first one, and use the second one, where as I feel that The second one is just a pain.

What's the benefit in the second one?

Comment: It's shorter to chain if the function returns the object which the function is called on. But it is better to separate if the function return some other thing.

Comment: You did not specify the language, only the semicolon gives a hint about it. Dot chaining is important and frequently used in Ruby.

Comment: @karatedog Your comment helps nothing. a he didnt ask about Ruby and b it being frequently used doesn't make it good (or at least unquestionable) practice - he is asking the very question of why some people feel that it should be avoided. Also, its obvious that the language doesnt matter unless you know some language that uses dot to refer to something else than properties/methods of an object (well you could say string concatenation, but then the braces don't fit).

Comment: I didn't answer **Ruby**, it was only an example. And the accepted answer is a clear proof that this question can be misunderstood. Dot chaining in Ruby works as pipe in Linux/Unix. If you want to `grep` a file, then modify the result with `sed` you don't implement a new utility that does both functionality. You chain them. Or you execute one, store the result, and then execute the other. You have to use one form from the OP. Which the accepted answer tells you not to do. Yet, the accepted answer is right, but in a totally different problem domain. Too bad this 1-question user has left SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid both forms.  The [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is an important guideline when writing software that states

> Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
>
> Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
>
> Only talk to your immediate friends.

You're violating this law because `someObject` knows that `bla2` has a `performBlah` method.  If it really does need to have this kind of method them move it to `someObject` and hide `bla1` and `bla2` from the outside world.

`someObject.getBla1().getBla2().performBlah()` would then become `someObject.performBlah()` and the internal implementation of `someObject.performBlah` would probably delegate to `bla1` which in turn would delegate to `bla2` to get the implementation.  The important thing is to make sure that each object only knows its immediate friends and doesn't reach out into the wider world (e.g. `someObject` only knows about `bla1`, `bla1` only knows about `bla2`).

Comment: thnx +1 for a great answer, Could you please also include an example code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid dot-chaining like the first example you give because in the case there is any failure like an Exception, you will get the line in which it happened. So, in the first case you have many calls in the same line. This way, you won't be able to know which of the calls thrown the exception (for example a null pointer exception). In the second example, even though it looks less "clean", it's actually easier to spot a failure as you will know exactly what call failed.

Answer (score 0):

The second provides a clearer understanding of what you're precisely doing, but I see no problem personally with doing the second as long as your objects and methods provide fluent interface.